# RedirectPermanent on localhost without contacting other domains

Tags: .htaccess

Lets says i have a .htaccess file with the following for Apache to redirect webbrowsers to a specifik iconfile.

```
RedirectPermanent /favicon.ico http://example.com/folder/icon.ico
```

So i guess when i test my website on localhost that every time the browser is looking for http://localhost/favicon.ico that it gets send to http://example.com/folder/icon.ico

How do i avoid this?

On localhost i would like for it to redirect to http://localhost/folder/icon.ico like:

```
RedirectPermanent /favicon.ico http://localhost/folder/icon.ico
```

What is the correct/optimal way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `mod-alias` is not very flexible to use variables so you should use `mod-rewrite`.

Not sure why you would want to do this anyway, but you can try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/icon.ico [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's because when I'm on localhost i dont want to redirect the browsers request for favicon.ico to the other domain. Some browsers automatically requests the file favicon.ico in the root of the website. But i dont want it there.